# Twilio Error - 12300 on Sinatra App Deployed on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, twilio

I am getting a weird issue using Twilio on a Sinatra App deployed with Heroku. I have an open ticket, but want to get the community's input on an issue. When I create my first MMS of the day to all my contacts in the DB, I get this error:

> ERROR  12300 Twilio is unable to process the Content-Type of the
>   provided URL. Please see the [Twilio Markup
>   XML Documentation](/docs/api/twiml/) for more information on valid Content-Types.

I get this on 30 out of 55 messages this code sends. However, if I run the same submission again, thru the same method, I get 0 errors. It all passes thru. I'm super confused. The only thing I can possibly think of is Twilio has trouble retrieving the IMG_URL on the initial request, maybe caches it for future use. I'm just guessing here. Anyone else have a similar problem with using Twilio on Heroku?

Here's the code I use to send:

```
#Twilio API Post from App
post '/send' do
  protected!
  #Save Devotional to DB
  @devotional = Devotional.create(from: params[:from],subject: params[:subject], body: params[:body])
  #Send Saved Devotional to SMS Twilio
  Contact.all.each do |contact|
    client.messages.create(
      from: TWILIO_NUMBER,
      to: contact.phone_number,
      body: @devotional.body.to_s,
      media_url: 'http://devotionalbroadcast.com/images/daily-broadcast-header.png'
    )
  end
  redirect '/'
end
```

Could HTTP AUTH have anything to do with it? I am using Sinatra's simple Auth but I don't think that would cause an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I tried to load the URL from your example there and the response headers were:

```
Date: Mon, 26 Feb 2018 05:57:03 GMT
Content-Length: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: thin
Via: HTTP/1.1 proxy10702
Keep-Alive: 60
```

There is no `Content-Type` header to tell Twilio what the content is. I would try to ensure your server is sending images with the correct MIME type, in this case `image/png` and see if that solves the issue.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Sorry I am just getting back to this issue. So, do I need to define this content type within the Twilio API request? Or do I need to define it thru Thin, which is spinning up the server. This is a unknown area for me hear. Thanks!

Comment: How are you serving that image? Is it through your Ruby application? I just loaded the image again and checked the headers and it now has a content-type (and the content-length is more than 0 too), which is promising. Have you tried this code again?

Comment: Image is served by my Sinatra App. I have tried the image request again. Does Heroku sleep certain portions of an App and wake on HTTP request? I'm thinking of migrating that media file to AWS to see if it's a Heroku issue. I also have a support ticket open with them to clarify.

Comment: Heroku will sleep your free dynos, if you pay for them they should stay awake. Are you still having problems with this then? Can you share the code in your Sinatra app that serves the image?

Comment: Got it sorted out. Had to migrate that image assedt to a S3 bin on AWS and it's all good. That's for the digging you guys prompted!

Comment: Glad it's all sorted!